# How to change the background of activity by file path?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, background

The scenario of APP is like the following.

The Splash Activity will run the Background for 3 second (To be the opening picture).

The Splash Activity use startActivity to call the MainActivity, and finish itself. And then , the MainActivity add the Fragment.

In this Fragment , it will choose a picture and get the uri by Uri uri = data.getData();.

And the Fragment transmit this uri to the first Activity(Splash Activity) by using Intent and startActivity.

The Splash Activity receive the uri and save it by SharedPreferences.

And the `Splash Activity` set the Background by using this uri.

But it has error

The code in Splash Activity is like the following:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    public static final String BACKGROUND_PATH = "path";
    private Context mContext;

    //private static String PATH;
    private String Background_path;
    private String temp;
    private static final String TAG = "MJPEG Player" ;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ;


        // Hides the titlebar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) ;

        setContentView(R.layout.splash) ;

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        Background_path = intent.getStringExtra(BACKGROUND_PATH);
        Log.i(TAG, "Background_path = " + Background_path);

        //If the image path receive from fragment is not empty , then save it.
        if(Background_path != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Background_path = " + Background_path);
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PATH", 0);
            settings.edit()
                .putString("name", Background_path)
                .commit();
        }

         //if the value in SharedPreferences is not empty , set it to the background

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.splash);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PATH", 0);
        String temp = settings.getString("name", "");
        if(temp != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "temp = " + temp);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(temp);  
            ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(uri));
                BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                relativeLayout.setBackground(background);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
```

And the error log is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(32541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:72)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
E/AndroidRuntime(32541):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  568):   Force finishing activity tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/.Splash
```

The code at `Splash.java:72` is `ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();`

How to solve this problem ?

Thanls in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not initialized `mContext` variable. and why you need a `mContext` inside an `Activity` as already `Activity` is a `Context`...

so you can replace `mContext.getContentResolver()` with `this.getContentResolver()`

Comment: Set the mContext = getActivity(); ??

Comment: no need of mContext varaible inside Activity. getContentResolver() method is available for Activity also as Activity extends Context...